# Keep timestamp header after using message store channel

Tags: spring-integration

I use a queue channel backed up with a message store and found that the timestamp header does not keep with the original value, is there a way to keep it?

here's my configuration

```
<int:channel id="myChannel">
    <int:queue message-store="myStore"/>
</int:channel>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: What `MessageStore` implementation do you use?

Comment: JdbcMessageStore

Comment: Try to use this one instead: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/jdbc/store/JdbcChannelMessageStore.java. See it’s JavaDocs for details

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I'm already using jdbcChannelMessageStore. I use Spring integration 4.3.1

Comment: Ok! Then it can be. Seems for me we fixed it in `5.0`

Comment: Thanks! could you please confirm this to me, because to fix it we must make an upgrade to 5.0, which could not be so easy. I search the jira for this issue but only found this related to jdbcChannelMessageStore https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4445

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for really has been fixed in the version `5.0`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1916.

Pay attention to my phrase there in the end of PR dfescription:

> With this fix we persist message in the store as is without any modifications when we perform standard serialization procedure.
>
> Any custom serializers should consider to use MutableMessageBuilder if there is a requirement to retain ID and TIMESTAMP

A default one is there like this:

```
public Message<?> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    return (Message<?>) this.deserializer.convert(this.lobHandler.getBlobAsBytes(rs, "MESSAGE_BYTES"));
}
```

So, we definitelly retain there incoming `ID` and `TIMESTAMP`.